# Unable to create an object of type 'MyContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, web, asp.net-core-mvc

Model :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System;

namespace Data
{
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string? Username { get; set; }
    public User()
    {
        
    }
}
}
```

Context :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

namespace Data
{
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User>? Users { get; set; }
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public MyContext()
    {
    }
 }
}
```

Connection string :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"MyContext" : "data source =(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=TestVsCodeDB;               Integrated Security=True ",
"providerName" :"System.Data.SqlClient"
}
```

[Slo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpv1y.png)

I use VS Code and I get this error during migration.
I used a similar method in asp.net mvc, but I get this error in asp.net core

Comment: how are you adding MyContext in program.cs ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added you `dbContext` in `startup` or `program.cs` ?
Are you doing the migration in the correct path? it should be something like this:

```
cd ./project_with_migrations_folder
dotnet ef --startup-project ../my_startup_project_path/ migrations add myMigration01
```

Comment: نمیدونم من رشته اتصال و دیتا بیس رو ساختم اما تو program.cs چیزی انجام ندادم

Comment: That's not enough, have you created the context file? it should inherit "DbContext" and include your "DbSet"s. then you should inject it in the program.cs

Answer (score 0):

You must use the default constructor of `MyContext.cs`. Remove

```
public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

In `Program.cs` do this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
string ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext");
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString));
}
```

Comment: سلام مرسی از جوابت اما من چون پروژه م جدیده گویا statup.cs نیست فقط program.cs هست که این کدو میذارم خطا میده

Comment: You use dot net 6, that's right? The new update in dot net 6 is you can write one class without the main body that is in use in Program.cs. You must write builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString)); in Program.cs